# Xcode 4.6 / Clang 4.2 can't find C++11 headers

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang, std

I'm trying to include some C++11 headers in an iOS project, but Xcode / Clang can't find them. I'm trying to include `<memory>`, `<functional>` and a few others. But it complains that it can't find them during the build (despite me right-clicking and "Jumping to definition" which loads the file...). How do I get my project to use C++11 header files?

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'memory' file not found
>   Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'functional' file not found

My project settings are:

> C++ Language Dialect = C++11 [-std=c++11]
>   C++ Standard Library = libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

The files which try to include the headers are `.h` for a templated class and a `.h` that is included from a `.mm` implementation.

Comment: Can you please show more code?

Comment: `<memory>` and `<functional>` are not new in C++11, can you find them if you don't use C++11 as the language dialect?

Comment: I'd previously commented incorrectly on what I thought was the issue, but I've seen this before when the `Compile Sources As` was set to something other than `According to file type`; additionally, if the `.mm` files' file type was set to something other than `Objective-C++` in the file inspector

Comment: reopened, time for answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out that Clang's error message was unhelpful: the root include for these files was a `.m` file, compiling as Objective-C, so I renamed it to `.mm`, to compile as Objective-C++, and it started working.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. My base class was an Objective-C source and I needed to change it to Objective-C++. Personally I just changed the file type in the sidebar, but it's essentially the same fix